# IAR Workbench can't find std::string

Tags: c++, embedded, shared-libraries, iar

I'm trying to compile [CppUTest](https://cpputest.github.io/manual.html) as a library on IAR Workbench v6.3.3 for the AVR UC3C0512C on Windows 7 x64 but when I compile it, it says that the std namespace is not defined.

Here is the snippet of code where I get the first error, the file is `SimpleString.h`:

```
#if CPPUTEST_USE_STD_CPP_LIB
  #include <string>
  #include <stdint.h>

  SimpleString StringFrom(const std::string& other);
```

The last line contains the `std::string` and this brings me 190 errors all related to this. The message is:

```
Error[Pe276]: name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name
C:\COM\SRC\cpputest35\include\CppUTest\SimpleString.h 143
```

I have tried using the line below but it does not help:

```
using namespace std;
```

[image]

Under Library Configuration I select Normal DLIB, I also tried with Full DLIB but IAR can't see the std library

[image]

Any ideas please?

Comment: AVR is supported by GCC which fully supports ISO C++ rather than EC++.  EC++ is largely obsolete.

Comment: We are in the process to migrate the project to GCC but it is not an easy task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the IAR manuals

```
The std namespace is not used in either standard EC++ or in Extended EC++. If you 
have code that refers to symbols in the std namespace, simply define std as nothing; 
for example:
#define std // Nothing here
```

Comment: @SnakeSanders: I would suggest in this case using a compiler command line macro definition (I guess on the "Preprocessor" options tab), rather than a `#define` to maintain portability of the code without needing to remove the definition or add conditional compilation around it - it is also the easiest way to add the definition globally to all existing and third-party code.

Comment: In order to use a compiler command you need to add the entry `std=` to the list of defined symbols. `std` will not work.